# Unable to add Acquia Cloud site using Acquia Dev Desktop behind a proxy (Win 7)

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I'm trying to use Acquia Dev Desktop 2 Beta behind a proxy at work (Win 7), but there doesn't seem to be any proxy configuration settings for the program.

When I try to log in to Acquia cloud, it times out and says:

> Login failed.
>   Network error: Couldn't connect to server

Has anyone figured out how to make this work through your proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is:
"Proxy configuration is currently not supported in the most recent version of Acquia Dev Desktop"

There are some workarounds, that work with varying levels of success, but nothing solid that I've found.

Comment: What are the workarounds that you have seen?

Comment: well, since I posted this, Acquia has updated Dev Desktop with built-in proxy support. It should be noted that each proxy connection string will most likely be different, so you'll need to speak with your firewall team.